# "Invidious" vs. "Insidious"

Tags: word-choice, differences, confusables

Can anyone give me a really short & sharp distinction between these two words? Are they notorious for often getting mixed up?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sorry, but Malvolio's answer is too simple in some parts, and the other parts are simply wrong. Let's see what NOAD has to say:

> **invidious** |inˈvidēəs|
>   *adjective*
>   (of an action or situation) likely to arouse or incur resentment or anger in others : *she'd put herself in an invidious position*.
>   • (of a comparison or distinction) unfairly discriminating; unjust : *it seems invidious to make special mention of one aspect of his work*.

That's not eVil. It's not even evil. It can be used as a pejorative, but it is decidedly not simply a synonym for bad.

> **insidious** |inˈsidēəs|
>   *adjective*
>   proceeding in a gradual, subtle way, but with harmful effects : *sexually transmitted diseases can be insidious and sometimes without symptoms*.
>   • treacherous; crafty : *tangible proof of an insidious alliance*.

This in a sense means "sneaky" — but that is far short of a definition. *Insidious* is actually more "evil" than *invidious*, as you can see.

If you need a mnemonic, use the "v" in *invidious* to represent the "v" in "visible": it's something you can see. If something is *insidious*, on the other hand, it's something harmful which derives its power from the fact that you don't notice it.

Comment: OK, that does it for me. Personally I think we should randomly select one of these words to be taken out and shot. At least the other one could have a reasonable life then.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: But they're so *cute* together!

Answer (score 1):

There's no Darth Vidious?

Or, invidious, with a v,  means "eVil"; insidious, with an s means "Sneaky".  Does that help?

Comment: Not bad! It's just been proposed to me out here in the "real" world that I should link *invidious* / *invader* and *insidious* / *sidling*, but I think I like yours better.

Comment: who came up with the second of these two words (whichever was coined second)?

Comment: @Mitch: I won't endear myself to the tribal elders here by admitting that so far I haven't even checked a dictionary for either word, but that's the truth. Am busy tonight so I'll look up more details tomorrow.

Comment: This is simply misleading the OP.

Comment: @Robusto -- Not it's not!  "That's not argument, [it's just contradiction](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wdoGVgj1MtY&feature=player_detailpage#t=114s)."