# Does "invidious" come implicit with malice or consideration? Or is it just absent of care?

Tags: meaning, connotation

"Invidious" [(the often misunderstood)](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/22451/invidious-vs-insidious) is known to involve harmful or threatening effects — at least insomuch as one party feels "resentful" or similarly about the situation.

So there are at least two 'parties' involved:

1. one that performs the action, or represents the situation
2. another that is *"aroused" to*, or "incurs" the "resentment or anger"

So my question is whether Party #1 does their acts, represents the situation ***with malice***?  Meaning: 'by design'.  Does "invidiousness" come implicit with *design* for the results of the actions?  Or is this intentionality then another word (e.g. "malice")

Alternatively, does 'invidiousness' come minimally with *consideration*?  Does Party #1 comprehend the capacity of their action(s) to incite resentfulness in Party #2?

My focus has come to the part of the definition that says "likely."  An "invidious" action is one that is "likely" to cause resentment, etc.  The OED may advance this dimension of the word even further:

> Of a charge, complaint, report, etc.: *Tending* or **fitted to** excite
>   odium, unpopularity, or ill feeling against some one.

(emphasis mine)

In either the case of a 'tendency' or a 'fitting' it would seem that the actor (#1) has, minimally, a consideration as to the invidious effect, namely *"odium, unpopularity, or ill feeling against some one."*

The [coup de grace](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/coup+de+grace) question: *must* invidiousness be absent of Care?  Can Party #1 act invidiously and still have compassion for Party #2?

---

At risk of involving too much thought about the metaphysics of intent - many of the comment center around *intent* and *unintended consequences* (unto Party #2).

Comment: In the sense that *invidious* means "unfairly or offensively discriminating" I find it hard not to attach malice to it; yet a person may act unfairly or offensively out of ignorance or oversight, so an imputation of malice may be an unfair characteriation.

Comment: I disagree with your very first assumption - that invidious necessarily implies "harmful or threatening effects". Harm or threat might or might follow an invidious act - whether they do is situational and not implied semantically.

Comment: As [laws](http://lawreview.law.ucdavis.edu/issues/42/1/articles/42-1_Higdon.pdf) and [inanimate objects](http://archive.org/details/cihm_20177) can be invidious the 'invidiousness' lies in the result rather than the intent, so I would say no - it does not require malice. That doesn't mean that it there is never malicious intent, just that it is not obligatory.

Comment: @MarkBeadles harmful, threatening, odious, ill-feelings are in the definition(s) of the word - how could it not "imply" those things?  Do you rather mean that these things were not the intent?

Comment: @RoaringFish a law is written by people (or a person) thus the author(s) can have intent.  An object is made by a person or 'by God', and thus have the intent of their creator.  Is the question becoming about the degree to which any *unintended consequences* is foreseeable?  Thus returns to why I ask if invidiousness is **absent of care**?

Comment: Ok, I see that you are focusing here on the intent of the invidious actor and not on the effects in the recipient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In American (and possibly British) legal usage, **invidious** does have a direct relation to **intent**.

One common meaning of "invidious" in law is "[motivated by ill will or malice](http://lists.ucla.edu/pipermail/conlawprof/2000-August/002105.html)". This speaks directly to intent and motivation. For example, "invidious discrimination" is that which is "motivated by...hostility or animus" [(EEOC v. Joe's Stone Crab, 2000)](http://www.ca11.uscourts.gov/opinions/ops/19985367.OPN.pdf). It is possible to discriminate harmfully without having specific intent to do so (for example, if one has a rational but mistaken belief about a group of people) -- but such cases are not 'invidious' even though harmful and illegal.

[This is informative about legal usage only, and not on general usage which may of course have broader use. Also, it doesn't address the psychological question about whether someone can simultaneous exhibit compassion and malice toward an individual, but that's out of scope here anyway.]